# Store and fetch image in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm making a simple Android application to show all the countries and their flags. I want to use Room and SQLite to store the flag images but I dont really know which is the best way.

I can store the Flag images as names such as "france" and later retrieve them with:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("france","drawable",requireActivity().getPackageName())
```

But I am warned that this will be really slow and with hundreds of countries the app wont be good. At the moment I have all the flag icons in the res/drawables folder, so what is the best way to save them into the database and retrieve later? Thank you.

Comment: why are you trying to save something you already have in res/drawables ?

Comment: Hi, because if I do not store the images, how can I associate, for example, the france.svg with the Country France object? 

I can retrieve images by R.drawable.france, but then I would have to check each country name to display the France flag. I dont know if Im making any sense :D

Comment: @trpn39 need to store it somewhere as HashMap/Map , Key is country name , value is drawable , you dont need to check just get key of that map!

Comment: @Nrohpos I havent thought of that. Thank you I will try to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to store drawables in Room DB, You have to convert it into `byteArray`.

```
Drawable d;
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

define column in room as byte[].

Comment: thanks for your answer but I decided to go with a solution in the comment. I will mark your answer anyways